# How to redirect search form action to specific URL

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a Search Form that will, based on selected option value, redirect the user after clicking on submit button.
Here is my Form code:

```
<form method="get" action="http://www.yourdomain.com/hotels/search" role="search">
    <option value="">Select Location</option>
    <option value="10">USA</option>
    <option value="3">Canada</option>
    <option value="4">Singapore</option>
    <option value="5">India</option>
    <option value="6">China</option>

    </select>
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

In the form action as you can see, it's set to:

> http://www.yourdomain.com/hotels/search

For Example: If we select USA, after submit, page will be redirected to this link:

> http://www.yourdomain.com/hotels/search/USA/USA/10?checkin=15%2F05%2F2016&checkout=16%2F05%2F2016&adults=1&child=0

But I want to redirect page like this:

> http://www.yourdomain.com/hotels/search/USA/USA/10?checkin=%F%F&checkout=%F%F&adults=1&child=0

I mean, to **remove checkin/checkout date**

How can I do it?

Comment: You COULD do it client side with some JavaScript detection and on-the-fly manipulation of the action attribute of the form, but the right way (read: how I would do it) is to submit the form to a script that takes the selected value, determines the appropriate destination and then performs a redirect or navigation to it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but you didn't mention how I can do it, I need JavaScript  detection, if you know please share it with me. thanks